# this program checks whether it is in the file text.txt that the user has received

Tags: python

If I remove these lines of code:

```
else:
  print("Boş")
  break
```

Then, the program seems to work fine, but when I add it again, the program does not find any words in the `text.txt` and throw a `Not found` exception.

Here is the full code:

```
class x():
         def __init__(self):
            with open('metin.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8")as file:
                 icerik = file.read()
                 icerik = icerik.split()
                 self.sade_kelime = []
                 self.sozluk = dict()
                 file.seek(0)
                 for i in icerik:
                     i = i.strip(".")
                     i = i.strip(",")
                     i = i.strip("")
                     self.sade_kelime.append(i)
                 for i in self.sade_kelime:
                     if i in self.sozluk:
                        self.sozluk[i] += 1
                     else:
                         self.sozluk[i] = 1
          def kelime_frekans(self):
                 for i in self.sozluk:
                     if i == kelime:
                      print(kelime, self.sozluk[i], "kez metinde geciyor")
                     else:
                      print("Boş")
                      break
        dosya = x()
        while True:
             kelime = input('kelime:')
             if kelime == "q":
                 break
             else:
                 dosya.kelime_frekans()
```

Comment: Forgive me for my english.

Comment: Which `else` are you referring to?  There are several.

Comment: @cdarke else:
                      print("Boş")
                      break

Comment: Your indentation appears to be inconsistent. I suggest reindenting the code in your question.

Comment: @nnnmmm I checked it's right.

Comment: do not `break` out of the loop

Comment: @hjpotter92 thansk, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if i == kelime` condition is not satisfy on first iteration, loop will break.
Logically this is not a correct code. Your `kelime_frekans` function should be like this:

```
def kelime_frekans(self):
        for i in self.sozluk:
            if i == kelime:
                print(kelime, self.sozluk[i], "kez metinde geciyor")
                return
        print("Boş")
```